# How do I get nodemon to run a complex command that is wrapped in quotations?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Here's the situation

```
nodemon ./app
```

works great.

```
nodemon "./app"
```

does not.

This results in nodemon constantly starting and restarting  without ever actually running `./app`. Why is this a relevant you may ask? Consider the following.

```
webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.config.js
```

I want to run the above with `nodemon` but `webpack-dev-server` and `nodemon` both use the `--config` flag. This means that I have to place the above command in quotations resulting in the following.

```
nodemon "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.config.js"
```

which dunt work. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
nodemon webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.config.js
```

Comment: Perfect! Question though, what is the functionality of the `--` before the `--config` flag?

Comment: @FinnM To tell nodemon stop slurping arguments. See `nodemon -h `